# Installing pyodbc on CentOS 5

Tags: python

I am trying to instal pyodbc. I did all the recommended steps, and keep getting this error:

```
python setup.py build<br>
running build<br>
running build_ext<br>
building 'pyodbc' extension<br>
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=3.0.7 -I/usr/include/python2.4 -c /home/hyelluas/pyodbc-3.0.7/src/getdata.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.4/home/hyelluas/pyodbc-3.0.7/src/getdata.o -Wno-write-strings<br>
/home/hyelluas/pyodbc-3.0.7/src/connection.h:27: error: âuintptr_tâ does not name a type
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Has anybody seen it? Any idea what to do next? I have look at the file `connection.h` and it looks good to me.

Comment: "I've edited that file connection.h" - probably a bad idea. It looks like you might have messed it up somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Management Summary:  This error suggests that you don't have your build environment set up right, OR that your build process is mucking things up a bit.

Details: `uintptr_t` is an optional part of the ISO C99 language spec and comes from stdint.h.  That said, I'm pretty sure GCC has had it for ages.  I'd check your compiler's include path to ensure that that file exists within it.  Possible sources of problems include:

1. Your build tools are not configured properly, and compiling most anything non-trivial shouldn't work if this is the case.
2. Your compiler is ancient and out of date.  That seems unlikely since CentOS shipped with..  GCC 4.1.2 (I think?), and I'm pretty sure that's plenty new enough.
3. Your build process here is somehow confusing GCC and getting it to not include the standard include path when compiling.  That seems the most likely option, but I'm not sure what the right solution would be exactly.

Hopefully that at least gives you a little more detail on what to look for.

Comment: Hi, I was having the same issue and thats only the first part, you can add an include stdin.h at the start of the file and it will pass the error but then you will have others. The bottom line is that you need python 2.7 at least to compile pyodbc